# $H_{n}:Comp(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$ is an additive functor implies $H_{n}:K(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$ is an additive functor.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

We know that if $\mathcal{A}$ is an abelian category, then the homology functor $H_{n}:Comp(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$ is an additive functor for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. One can find a prove of this statement in Rotman´s Homological Algebra Proposition 6.8. But sometimes why the same holds for $H_{n}:K(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$,  where $K(\mathcal{C})$ is the homotopy category ? Maybe my question is simple and silly but for example if I have $[f],[g] \in K(\mathcal{C})$ I need to prove among other things that $H_{n}([gf])=H_{n}([g])H_{n}([f])$ or that as  $K(\mathcal{C})$ is also an additive category then $H_{n}([f+g])=H_{n}([f])+H_{n}([f])$. Is there a way to easily prove this if its already proved in the category of complexes. Also how I know $H_{n}([f])$ is well defines if I already know that the assignation $H_{n}(f)$ is well defined. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little more comfortable working with cohomology, so I'm going to answer this question in that language; of course the concepts are dual, so simply dualizing gives you the corresponding result for homology. The easiest way (in my opinion, anyway) to see that the cohomology functors
$$
H^n:K(\mathscr{A}) \to \mathscr{A}
$$
are additive for any Abelian category $\mathscr{A}$ is to use the universal property of the homotopy category. By definition, the category
$$
K(\mathscr{A}) = \mathbf{Ch}(\mathscr{A})_{/\text{homotopy}}
$$
is a strict localization, i.e., it is given by inverting a congruence relation. It also follows from the bilinearity of chain homotopies (i.e. if $f \simeq g$ and $h \simeq k$ then $f + g \simeq f + k \simeq g + h \simeq h + k$) that the quotient functor
$$
q:\mathbf{Ch}(\mathscr{A}) \to K(\mathscr{A})
$$
is also additive. Now recall that applying the universal property of a localization of categories says that in our case if you have a functor $F:\mathbf{Ch}(\mathscr{A}) \to \mathscr{C}$ which kills homotopy (so if $g \simeq h$ then $Fg = Fh$) then there exists a unique functor $\overline{F}:K(\mathscr{A}) \to \mathscr{C}$ making the diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \mathbf{Ch}(\mathscr{A}) & \xrightarrow{F} & \mathscr{C} \\
 q\downarrow & \nearrow & \\
 K(\mathscr{A})
\end{array}
$$
where the diagonal arrow is $\overline{F}$. In the case we actually care about, we use the functor $H^n:\mathbf{Ch}(\mathscr{A}) \to \mathscr{A}$ and produce the commuting diagram of categories
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\\
 \mathbf{Ch}(\mathscr{A}) & \xrightarrow{H^n} & \mathscr{A} \\
 q\downarrow & \nearrow & \\
 K(\mathscr{A})
\end{array}
$$
where in this case the diagonal arrow is the cohomology functor on the homotopy category (which I will denote $\overline{H}^n$ for the moment. To see that this is additive, we just need to prove that $\overline{H}^n$ preserves finite products. For this we first consider the zero object $0_K \in K(\mathscr{A})_0$ and note that $0_K \cong q(0_C)$ for $0_C$ the zero object in $\mathbf{Ch}(\mathscr{A})$. Then
$$
\overline{H}^n(0_K) \cong \overline{H}^n(q(0_C)) = H^n(0_C) \cong 0_{\mathscr{A}}.
$$
Now fix two arbitrary complexes $A^{\bullet}, B^{\bullet} \in \mathbf{Ch}(\mathscr{A})_0$ and consider the product $A^{\bullet} \times B^{\bullet}$. We note that because $q$ is additive and acts as the identity on objects, we have that
$$
A^{\bullet} \times B^{\bullet} = q(A^{\bullet}) \times q(B^{\bullet}) \cong q(A^{\bullet} \times B^{\bullet}).
$$
Now using the additivity of $H^n$ and the fact that $H^n = \overline{H}^n \circ q$ gives
$$
\overline{H}^n(A^{\bullet} \times B^{\bullet}) \cong \overline{H}^n(q(A^{\bullet} \times B^{\bullet}) = H^n(A^{\bullet} \times B^{\bullet}) \cong H^n(A^{\bullet}) \times H^n(A^{\bullet}) \cong \overline{H^n}(q(A^{\bullet})) \times \overline{H^n}(q(B^{\bullet})) = \overline{H}^n(A^{\bullet}) \times \overline{H}^n(B^{\bullet}),
$$
which proves that $\overline{H}^n$ preserves finite products. We can thus conclude that $\overline{H}^n$ is an additive functor, as was desired.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Your proof was very clear, just wondering if there is any book where they claim $H_{n}$ or $H^{n}$ is an additive funtor for $K(\mathcal{C})$ instead of complexes, to reference. @Geoff

Comment: @Cos this is done, for instance, in Kashiwara-Schapira's book ``Categories and Sheaves.'' I think the overkill explicit reference you would want is Corollary 12.3.4, to be a little more precise.